# Ember.js: Prevent destroying of views

Tags: ember.js

I have my routes setup like this:

```
this.resource('post',{path:":post_id"},function(){
    this.resource('selectimage',{path:"selectimage/:returncontext"},function(){    });
});
```

Both post.index and selectimage are rendered into separate outlets:

```
// PostIndexRoute
renderTemplate: function (controller) {
    this.render({ outlet: 'detailColumn' });
},

// SelectimageRoute
renderTemplate: function (controller) {
    this.render({ outlet: 'modal' });
},
```

When I navigate from post to post/selectimage, the post.index view is destroyed ("willDestroyElement" is called).
And when I navigate back to selectimage post.index needs to be re-rendered.

Can I prevent this behavior and just keep the views in place until I really leave the post resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Index route under post, just use the PostRoute/PostController/Post template instead, those won't be destroyed when you visit resources below them.

Essentially the index route is a different path than the selectimage path, so it's removed when you navigate there.

Comment: Yep. Should have seen that earlier :) Thanks