# How to prevent views from being destroyed in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

**Quick note:**

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Ember.js: Prevent destroying of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956885/ember-js-prevent-destroying-of-views). Other related questions that I've found are out-of-date.

In case this becomes out-of-date later, I am using Ember 1.7.0 with Handlebars 1.3.0.

---

**Context for the question:**

As the title states, I am wondering how to transition between views without destroying them. Using `queryParams` does *not* solve my issue.

I am creating a calculator with the following nested views:

```
>>Calculator View
    >>Report View (hasMany relationship to Calculator)
      --School Partial (I am using queryParams here)
```

I am able to navigate between the `Report` views just fine without destroying my `School` partial, since I am using `queryParams` and using a `displaySchoolPartial` boolean to show/hide the partial. Example below:

Report template (stripped to only show the essential part):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="calculator/report">
    ...
    {{#link-to "calculator.report" (query-parameters displaySchoolPartial="true")}}
    {{render "_school"}}
</script>
```

School template (also stripped down):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_school">
    {{#with controllers.calculatorReport}}
    <div {{bind-attr class=":schoolPartialWrapper displaySchoolPartial::hide-element"}}>
        ...
    </div>
    {{/with}}
</script>
```

This works as expected. Navigating between different `Report` views and `School` partials, as stated before, does not destroy the view.

---

**The problem:**

My problem comes when navigating to the `Calculator` view, the `Report` view is destroyed, which then destroys my `School` view. I do not want to also use `queryParams` to replace my `Report` views.

The reason I need to make sure the views aren't destroyed is because I have a select box with 3,000 schools in my `School` partial. It takes too long to re-render this. It would be a much better UX to simply show/hide the `Report` views.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight with Ember. You will lose.

Views are instantiated and rendered when needed and torn down when done.

Why do you have a 3000-element dropdown, anyway?

If you really, really want to do this, what I would suggest is putting a `{{render}}` on your application page, and hide it. The view will be created and rendered when the app comes up and persist as long as the app is alive. Then, in the `didInsertElement` of your view, do a `cloneNode` of that hidden element and insert it into the view's DOM somewhere. You may have to muck around getting event handlers wired up correctly.

Comment: I agree 100% with your first sentence. I've already changed my implementation. I just mostly want to know now out of curiosity.

Comment: Regarding the use of `{{render}}` though, I'm already using that for the `School` partial. If I used it for the `Report` partial, how would I be able to define the route? Does it just work if it's in the usual `App.Router.map` function?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is not using "render" but using "partial", so you only need to drop in the template that you want. Have a control variable that set show/hide via css class. And control that variable using you controllers.

Using "partial" will allow you to have school template independent from report, thereby removing report will not affect school.

Just make sure you define the outlet and partial correctly.

Hope it helps!